# Robot Framework can't find chromedriver in PATH variable

Tags: automation, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I want to use Chrome for automation test with Robot Framework. Here are my settings:

```
*User variables:*
name: webdriver.chrome.driver
value: C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe

name: PATH
values: ......;C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
```

My code:

```
*** Settings ***

Library  BuiltIn
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  SikuliLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${HOST} =  VM
${URL} =  http://VM.com

${BROWSER} =  Chrome


*** Test Cases ***
Begin Web Test
    Open Browser  ${URL}   ${BROWSER}
    maximize browser window
```

After execution of command: pybot test.robot:

```
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No brows
er is open
Test Case                                                             FException
 AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method
Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x000000
0003670278>> ignored
Test Case                                                             | FAIL |
Setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Plea
se see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH" means that the *location* of chromedriver needs to be in the path. In your case, path needs to be "...;C:\chromedriver_win32". PATH contains folders, not executables.

Answer (score 2):

Download Chromedriver.exe from its official website, extract the .exe file and copy this .exe file in scripts folder of Python installation, e.g. C:\Python36\Scripts

After this, add this scripts path in Environment variable, as below:

[image: Path Environment Variable]

and now execute your test case.